# DataGrid перенос текста по словам

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpf, style

Сколько искал, находил только [один](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503262/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-cell-text-wrapping) вариант, как можно сделать перенос на другую строку по словам. 
Как можно применить это для всех текстовых столбцов?

Comment: Очевидно, что необходимо сделать стиль элемента и подставить его для колонки DataGrid. Наверное ниже вам должны объяснить в более разжеванном виде :)

Comment: Я не знаю, как сделать стиль для ElementStyle. Его можно определить для DataGridTextColumn, но я не понимаю как получить доступ к ElementStyle

Answer (score 1):

Примерно вот так.

```
<Style TargetType="DataGrid" x:Key="MyGrid">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding DataGrid.ItemsSource}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding Path=direction}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Колонка 1" Width="*" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellTextWrap}"  />
                        <DataGridTextColumn CanUserSort="False" Binding="{Binding Path=count}" ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="Колонка 2" Width="90" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellTextWrap}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Стиль для ячейки

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" x:Key="DataGridCellTextWrap">
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"></Setter>
    </Style>
```